# Will restoring from Time Machine carry over hard disk error?

Tags: time-machine

The Disk Utility detects some hard disk errors(inode problem, size mismatch). I am going to upgrade to a new hard drive and use Time Machine to restore the system, but I am worried that these existing hard disk errors may get copied over to the new hard drive. Does anyone know whether Time Machine restore will inherit these errors?Or will it be smart enough to restore the files cleanly to the new hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way filesystem errors like those you describe could be copied onto a different disk (e.g. your Time Machine volume) is if the whole disk partition or whole drive were copied at the block level using `dd` or something like Carbon Copy Cloner.  Time Machine doesn't work that way, so its stored backups should be free from the filesystem errors and the files it restores should be free from them as well.